# Can anyone help me find the big theta run-time complexity

Tags: runtime-error, time-complexity, big-o

I am new to the concept of Big Theta ( **Θ** )run-time complexity,

I have the following recurrence relations to analyze,

**T(n) = 2T(n/3) + 5n<sup>2</sup>**   and I got **Θ(<sup>2</sup>)**

**T(n) = T(n/4) + n<sup>4</sup>**     and I got **Θ(n<sup>4</sup>)**

Please verify my answers.

Answer (score 1):

Your answers are correct. 
You can solve these kind of problems by applying Master Theorem.

The Link is to Master Theorem,

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Generic_form

If **T(n) = a T(n/b) + f(n)** where a >= 1 and b > 1

We need to consider case 3 of Master Theorem,

Case 3: if **f(n) = Θ(n<sup>c</sup>)**  where **c > log<sub>b</sub>a**

Then **T(n) = Θ(n<sup>c</sup>)**

**First recurrence**

T(n) = 2T(n/3) + 5n<sup>2</sup>

a = 2, b = 3 and f(n) = 5 n<sup>2</sup>

There for, f(n) = Θ(n<sup>c</sup>), where c = 2.

Now c > log<sub>b</sub>a since 2 > log<sub>3</sub>2.

Thus T(n) = Θ(n<sup>2</sup>) as mentioned by you.

**Second Recurrence**

T(n) = T(n/4) + n<sup>4</sup>

a = 1, b = 4 and f(n) = n<sup>4</sup>

There for, f(n) = Θ(n<sup>c</sup>), where c = 4.

Now c > log<sub>b</sub>a since 4 > log<sub>4</sub>1.

Thus T(n) = Θ(n<sup>4</sup>) as mentioned by you.

Answer (score 0):

These are both correct. Because the second term of each recurrence equation is of a much higher order than the first, it will dominate the first term (in layman's terms).

Comment: Will this be the same for asking the big theta algorithmic complexity?